# Unable to connect to Azure hosted SQL Database from within Windows Docker container

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, docker, model-view-controller

I am unable to connect to my Azure hosted SQL database from within the Docker container, the application is an ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.7 application running on a Windows hosted Docker container with IIS.

My connection string looks like this:

```
data source=tcp:[hostname],1433;initial catalog=
```

[image]

I believe this could be a DNS issue or something with the connection string, has anyone had this problem before? When I run the app locally or within Visual Studio w/IIS Express it works perfectly; when run from inside the container, it is refusing to connect to the Azure SQL database. It isn't a firewall or rules issue since I can connect from my host machine just fine, it's something to do with the docker container.

Exception is:

> SqlException - A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.)

Comment: When using an Azure Hosted Database you need to ensure that the IP can access the Database. Have you added your IP to the allows list?

Comment: Yes, wouldn’t my local PC have the same IP address as the docker I’m hosting? And it’s working when I run it outside the docker container on the same machine.

Comment: when you build docker image manually, using docker build command, does the process finish successfully?

Comment: Yes it does complete. Because the app displays with the mapped port to port 443 (SSL) it’s just when the app tries to connect to the database it times out and gives this database connection error.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I'm having the same problem @MattDrouillard